# AFNetworking responseObject alternates between NSArray and NSDictionary in AFHTTPRequestOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have a problem using AFNetworking in AFHTTPRequestOperation. The responseObject alternates between NSArray and NSDictionary. Here is how I do a GET request:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:requestURL parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
      NSLog(responseObject[@"NotAvailableKey"];
    }    
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

The problem is when I'm trying to access a field which is not set in the NSArray object I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc1afaa0'
```

If the responseObject is of the type NSDictionary it works perfectly. Here is my JSON which I get:

```
(
        {
        "food_id" = 15;
        "food_name" = "fish";
        "user_admin_id" = 3;
        ingredients =         (
                        {
                "ingredients_id" = 3;
                "ingredients_name" = "salt";
            }
        );
    }
)
```

Comment: "The responseObject alternates between NSArray and NSDictionary" alternates for the same url or when different urls are used?

Comment: same base url put other method. Like http://baseurl.com/methodOne or http://basurl.com/methodTwo

Comment: You should learn to interpret those exceptions.  The one you got basically meant: Hey, `NSArray` does not respond to the `length` message, and you should never have sent it that message.  Since you are confused about what type of object you have, or you are confused about what message you want to send, I'm going to do you a favor and throw an exception.  It will probably kill your program, but that's better than letting you continue to do stuff that does not make sense.

Comment: @JodyHagins is right.
Neither `NSDictionary` nor `NSArray` responds to selector length. Thats `NSString` stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFNetworking is just a pipe between your app and the server, you give the impression you think its results should always be the same.

Using isKindOfClass is not the solution either. Your code should know what the expected format and content is when  baseurl.com/methodOne is called and how that differs when  baseurl.com/methodTwo is called and how that differs when  baseurl.com/methodN is called.

If you are calling baseurl.com/methodA you should know that the server is returning the data as an array and what it contains, if you are calling baseurl.com/methodB you should know now its a dictionary and what that contains. Doing it otherwise is the *wrong way round*.

Comment: There could be some situations where the server response is different depending on the request. Using NSDictionary is nice because I could try to access a certain value which is not available and nothing happened. However using NSArray I have to know all possible cases to handle the response gracefully.

Comment: @seven-ply You can ask the array how many objects it has, or you can use fast enumeration to go through all objects.  Then you won't have to guess about a certain index

Comment: " is different depending on the request". But it is your code that is making that request so when you get the response you know what the content *should* be, rather than trying to write generic code to see if a result might be there or not. Its cutting corners and hacky to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the `responseObject` is an `NSDictionary` or an `NSArray` before using it.

```
if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSLog([responseObject valueForKey:@"error"]);
}else if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
    //This is an NSArray, you cannot call 'valueForKey' on this responseObject
}
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by @Sausages in the comments, this should be used as a recovery for bad server response. You shouldn't handle multiple object types coming from a single server call has a normal behaviour or use the same methods to handle multiple server calls return an do the response handling according to its type.

Comment: How can I handle than my explained error? If I'm trying to access a value which is not available I'm getting the InvalidArgumentException

Comment: Like this: NSLog([responseObject valueForKey:@"error"]);

Comment: @seven-ply I updated my answer. The `NSLog` needs to be in the part of the code where you have checked that the `responseObject` is indeed an `NSDictionary`

Comment: Ah ok so how could I handle the problem gracefully If I access a certain value which is not available in the NSArray?

Comment: @seven-ply "how could I handle the problem gracefully If I access a certain value which is not available in the NSArray?" You should not be getting in that situation in the first place, you should not end up in a situation where you are looking for a value that is not there.

Comment: This is the wrong way round, the code should not be "if the response is a dictionary do this, else if its an array do that". It should be "if the server is sending an array then read an array, else if the server is sending a dictionary, then read a dictionary".

Comment: @Sausages It depends in what kind of situation he is in. I always check the `class` of an `id` object before using it because I don't want my app to crash if my backend goes nuts and don't send me what I expected (happened to me before and I had no control over it). You can know what you backend should return, but you can't guarantee it always will. My advice of using `isKindOfClass` is to prevent crash if the backend don't send what he expects.

Comment: @Emile I agree with what you are saying (additionally I would assert and panic in a  debug builds to catch the server going nuts during the development phase). However the OP seems pretty inexperienced and I think he thinks this is a way of directly the logic flow and its ok to look for things that aren't there and recover if not, rather than it being a safety check.

Comment: @Sausages I couldn't agree more with you :)